# changing CharSequence first letter to upper case in android

Tags: java, android, string, uppercase

it may seem simple but it posses lots of bugs 
I tried this way:

```
 String s = gameList[0].toString();
s.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)),String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))) );
```

and it throws an exception

another try i had was :

```
String s = gameList[0].toString();
char c = Character.toUpperCase(gameList[0].charAt(0));
gameList[0] = s.subSequence(1, s.length());
```

rhis one also throws an Exception

Comment: The Exception you get might help people answer this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

. . . or do it all in an array. Here's something similar.

```
    String titleize(String source){
        boolean cap = true;
        char[]  out = source.toCharArray();
        int i, len = source.length();
        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            if(Character.isWhitespace(out[i])){
                cap = true;
                continue;
            }
            if(cap){
                out[i] = Character.toUpperCase(out[i]);
                cap = false;
            }
        }
        return new String(out);
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

```
/**
 * returns the string, the first char lowercase
 *
 * @param target
 * @return
 */
public final static String asLowerCaseFirstChar(final String target) {

    if ((target == null) || (target.length() == 0)) {
        return target; // You could omit this check and simply live with an
                       // exception if you like
    }
    return Character.toLowerCase(target.charAt(0))
            + (target.length() > 1 ? target.substring(1) : "");
}

/**
 * returns the string, the first char uppercase
 *
 * @param target
 * @return
 */
public final static String asUpperCaseFirstChar(final String target) {

    if ((target == null) || (target.length() == 0)) {
        return target; // You could omit this check and simply live with an
                       // exception if you like
    }
    return Character.toUpperCase(target.charAt(0))
            + (target.length() > 1 ? target.substring(1) : "");
}
```

Comment: my problem was so trivial its all about null string

Answer (score 2):

#### On String being immutable

Regarding your first attempt:

```
String s = gameList[0].toString();
s.replaceFirst(...);
```

Java strings are immutable. You can't invoke a method on a string instance and expect the method to modify that string. [`replaceFirst`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead returns a *new* string. This means that these kinds of usage are wrong:

```
s1.trim();
s2.replace("x", "y");
```

Instead, you'd want to do something like this:

```
s1 = s1.trim();
s2 = s2.replace("x", "y");
```

---

As for changing the first letter of a `CharSequence` to uppercase, something like this works ([as seen on ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/xPEoV)):

```
    static public CharSequence upperFirst(CharSequence s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            return s;
        } else {
            return Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0))
                + s.subSequence(1, s.length()).toString();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
            "xyz", "123 abc", "x", ""
        };
        for (String s : tests) {
            System.out.printf("[%s]->[%s]%n", s, upperFirst(s));
        }
        // [xyz]->[Xyz]
        // [123 abc]->[123 abc]
        // [x]->[X]
        // []->[]

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("blah");
        System.out.println(upperFirst(sb));
        // prints "Blah"
    }
```

This of course will throw `NullPointerException` if `s == null`. This is often an appropriate behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this simpler solution for names, where toUp is an array of full names split by (" "):

```
for (String name : toUp) {
    result = result + Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + 
             name.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " ";
}
```

And this modified solution could be used to uppercase only the first letter of a full String, again toUp is a list of strings:

```
for (String line : toUp) {
    result = result + Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + 
             line.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Hope this helps.